# In python, how do I go back to the unedited mesh?

Tags: python, mesh

I am trying to do the following:

1. use a mesh to knife project onto another mesh
2. duplicate the faces that have been cut
3. extrude the duplicated faces by a given amount

in one operation.

I have asked about extrusion in a separate question, but I am also stuck at how do I return the mesh that's been knife-projected to its original state. This is because I only need the duplicate faces - the mesh that's projected onto should stay unchanged.

What I tried is:

```
# save mesh data - s is the object being projected onto
or_s_data = s.data.copy()

# do a bunch of things

s.data = or_s_data
# this should assign the saved mesh data, right?
# but actually it doesn't seem to
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
# don't know if this is necessary
```

So what's the right way to save a mesh's state, and re-instate it after a series of ops?

Comment: It depends if you modifiy `or_s_data` in between

Comment: @Gorgious - nope, I do not. The purpose is to restore it to the state before the knife project steps. Though I think that for future searchers an answer that covers changing things too might be interesting...